# How can I add new autostart programs in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, autostart

In Lubuntu, there's no 'Add New Program...' button in Desktop Session Settings. Is there an easy way to add new autostart programs in Lubuntu?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### For Lubuntu 11.10 / 12.04 / 12.10 / 13.04 / 14.04 / 14.10 / 16.04

Open the file manager (by default PCManFM), go to `/usr/share/applications`. Right-click on the program you want to be added to your autostart programs, and click `Copy`. Now, go to `~/.config/autostart` in PCManFM, right-click and click `Paste`. The program should be added to your autostart programs now, but double-check by clicking the LXMenu down left, click `Settings`, and then `Desktop Session Settings`.

You may have to create the `autostart` folder. For an application that doesn't have a *.desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` you may also copy-paste any other *.desktop then update it with content suitable for your app.

Comment: Not working for me, fresh install Lubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Can confirm that it works for Lubuntu 14.10

Comment: Just tried and it's working in Lubuntu 16.10. To verify using the GUI, go to the LXMenu > Preferences > Default applications for LXSession and select the Autostart tab. In the Known Applications list, check to see that the added applications are listed and checked.

Comment: Still works in 20.04.3 :)

Answer (score 13):

**For Lubuntu 19.04+**

Click on *Menu > Preferences > LXQt settings > Session Settings*

[image: Menu > Preferences > LXQt settings > Session Settings]

Click on *Autostart* in the left pane of the window that appears:

[image: Add applications to Autostart]

In here, you can type in the appropriate command or search for an application to be included and even remove items you don't wish to autostart.

Comment: Is anyone aware where config file is written?

Answer (score 9):

### For Lubuntu 13.10

`~/.config/autostart` trick does not work in Lubuntu 13.10, but commands which are put in `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` file will be run automatically after login. Read more about it in [this Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182986&p=12825759#post12825759).

If you want to do it graphically, go to `Preferences/Default applications for LX Session`, then select the `Autostart` tab.

Answer (score 5):

### For Lubuntu 13.10

In my example, I'll autostart `cairo-dock`.

1. Create a file called `.starter` in your home dir and make it executable:

   ```
   touch ~/.starter
   chmod +x ~/.starter
   ```
2. In that file write the command you want to be autostarted, save and close:

   ```
   leafpad ~/.starter
   ```
3. Edit the autostart file in the lxsession directory:

   ```
   sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
   ```
4. Add this new line:

   ```
   @/home/user/.starter ## Replace user by your name
   ```
5. Save and close
6. Reboot and it shall now run automaticaly

Comment: Not worked for me :(

Answer (score 3):

Make a new shorcut to the program in your ~/.config/autostart directory.

For example, to make the drop-down terminal Guake start automatically, type this in a terminal:

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
ln -s /usr/share/applications/guake.desktop guake.desktop
```

Comment: Maybe you can expand your answer to explain how!

Answer (score 3):

In Lubuntu (Ubuntu) 17.10, I succeeded in using the file:

```
.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do this a few times and the .desktop 'trick' never works for me. add the command to the autostart file: `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/146457/how-do-i-add-startup-applications-in-lubuntu-lxde) for details.

Answer (score 1):

you can manage them after installing lxsession-edit but don't know if that's what you want to achieve. otherwise the other answers are pretty good, the "official" guide is here: http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession#Autostarted_applications_using_lxsession

Answer (score 1):

#### For Lubuntu 18.04

1. Find the path of the application that you like to autostart.
2. Add the path to the application to `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`
3. Or use the tool under the menu ***Preferences->Default applications*** for ***LXSession***

   - select the ***Autostart*** tab
   - enter the path in the text field next to the ***+ Add*** button
   - click the ***+ Add*** button
4. ***Logout*** and ***Login*** to test

Answer (score 0):

[There's a thread about this on the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182986&p=12880964#post12880964).

I'm using Lubuntu 13.04 on a Samsung NC110 netbook, 2GB RAM.

A procedure that worked for me was:

1. `cd /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu`
2. `sudo nano autostart`
3. Add programs wanted, save and exit.

Directly putting cli commands in autostart file causes lxsession user preferences to not load, thus I added `bash filename.sh` into autostart (no `/bin/` pathname necessary) and achieved my purpose)

I had originally wanted to try to

1. reactivate LibreOffice Quickstarter

   - Make bash file with `libreoffice --quickstart --nologo –nodefault`
   - Place `bash filename.sh` in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/Autostart` file) and have pcmanfm to autostart up to my most commonly used directory (`pcmanfm pcmanfm /media/a/LG/AC/Learn/`).

Again, hope everyone can learn from my mistake. Definitely do not put regular cli commands directly into Autostart and expect them to execute normally, neither my desktop background, pcmanfm preferences (specifically the directory would open in icon view rather than my preference which is detailed view), nor my symbolic links loaded each time after bootup, and I was left with a desolate gray screen.

As soon as I deleted the cli commands and replaced it with bash file names, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [Exeleration-G's](https://askubuntu.com/users/18510/exeleration-g) graphical plan for adding VirtualBox in autostart.
I expected it to work when I logged out and in again, but the first time it didn't. I rebooted the computer and it started right up.  Ever since then, it loads when I log out and log back in again even when I closed V'Box before logging out.

I am using Lubuntu 16.04 LTS.