# how to add f.lux to startup applications on lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, startup-applications

I installed [f.lux](http://justgetflux.com/) on lubuntu and want to add it to startup application.

How can I find `f.lux` location at file system and add it to startup application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For ubuntu:**

To add to startup from your dash search fpr startup applications

[image]

Enter your desired name

In the command browse to the : `/usr/bin/fluxgui`

[image]

save and that's it

**## For Lubuntu  ##**

Open the file manager (by default PCManFM), go to `/usr/share/applications`. Right-click on the program you want to be added to your autostart programs, and click `Copy`. Now, go to `~/.config/autostart` in PCManFM, right-click and click `Paste`. The program should be added to your autostart programs now, but double-check by clicking the LXMenu down left, click `Settings`, and then `Desktop Session Settings`.

You may have to create the `autostart` folder. For an application that doesn't have a *.desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` you may also copy-paste any other *.desktop then update it with content suitable for your app.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81383/how-can-i-add-new-autostart-programs-in-lubuntu/81385#81385)

Comment: Lubuntu doesn't have dash !