# how to run applications after start in openbox automatically?

Tags: autostart, openbox

So, i decided to run openbox, but how do i set that after logging in i automatically xfce4-panel and nitrogen starts up?!

I looked here something, but that only speaks about unity.

Comment: I think you want to put .desktop files in the autostart folder: http://askubuntu.com/questions/81383/how-can-i-add-new-autostart-programs-in-lubuntu should apply to you.

Comment: what do you mean .desktop files? can you explain yourself more?!

Comment: Okay, see this post. They are the launchers of ubuntu (like desktop shortcuts on windows). http://askubuntu.com/questions/281293/creating-a-desktop-file-for-a-new-application

Comment: @havarka Did Tim's advice solve your problem?

Comment: I changed to lubuntu, I figured out it would be easier for me.