# How to start a Python script in LXTerminal using crontab at boot-up

Tags: python, cron

I have a script called myscript.py (in `/home/pi`) that I want to run in the terminal every time the Pi boot up.

I want to activate this by using 'crontab'. However after searching and trying stuff out I'm still no closer then when I was at the start.

Comment: crontab or startup, which of the two? furthermore, especially when using crontab, what is the script and what should it do?

Comment: Anything that needs to run in an LXTerminal needs a user session: see for example [How can I add new autostart programs in Lubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81383/how-can-i-add-new-autostart-programs-in-lubuntu)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I think crontab can do actions at startup.

Comment: @don.joey I think so too, but I think he means on log in, since he wants to run it in the terminal :)