# Starting browser after boot without starting full GUI

Tags: boot, gui, cron, chromium

I want to open a website on startup and use as less as possible from the GUI.
I have chromium installed so the command to run the website would be.

```
chromium-browser --kiosk URL
```

But how can I put it into auto start (crontab might work) **and** how to start less of the GUI (using LXDE) to save resources.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put your command in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Could you set init=</path/to/chromium> in the kernel line in grub? Random guess.

Comment: You might dig a bit deeper into how [lightdm](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) works as you will need a display manager. There you might define your own "greeter" to start only chromium (see [Write a lightdm greeter](http://www.mattfischer.com/blog/?p=5). Alternatively, configure lightdm for autologin and configure the user session for only running chromium.

Answer (score 1):

This Question is asked completely differently but has the same answer [How can I add new autostart programs in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81383/how-can-i-add-new-autostart-programs-in-lubuntu)

But in your case you would need to find a line in the .desktop file for chromium found in /usr/share/applications and change the exec line to chromium-browser --kisok URL

Although keep in mind starting LXDE will start lxpanel which I am not sure will be what you want with a kisosk.