# Script won't autostart despite making a .desktop file, placing directory in rc.local etc

Tags: scripts, lubuntu, autostart

I am trying to autostart a music player when my Lubuntu boots but I can't seem to get it to work. I am fairly new to Linux systems and have searched the internet for hours but I am out of ideas.
This is a .desktop file I made:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Script
Exec=/home/t/script.sh
Icon=home/t/script.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
X-KeepTerminal=true
StartupNotify=false
```

When I manually start it it works perfectly.
I've added this file in:

- `/.config/autostart`
- `/etc/xdg/autostart`
- `/usr/share/applications`

At: `/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu` I added the line

```
@/home/t/dtest.desktop
```

I also added the directory to `rc.local`

Comment: you don't need a .desktop file, just add `/home/t/script.sh` to startup applications.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried adding script.sh to the directories but it still didn't work. I was using a .desktop file to force the script to execute in terminal because otherwise it does not work.

Comment: What does `/home/t/script.sh` do?

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable and easy way of eadling with setting up autostart scripts is doing it using tools from your Desktop Enviroment.

I think answer for your question is here:
[How can I add new autostart programs in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81383/how-can-i-add-new-autostart-programs-in-lubuntu)

(you should look at answer: `For Lubuntu 19.04+`)